# Update Value dynamically using repeated Ajax calls from DJango template

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I wanted to show my sound sensor readings from a django site (original code as posted in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170851/showing-sensor-reading-in-a-django-website/)). Now as per the situation 2 of the accepted answer, I wanted to make a Javascript function which repeatedly calls the ajax_data function from views template.

But it seems that no repeated calls are being made. And no update in reading reflects either.

My django template till now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Noise measurement site</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"
     integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function updateValue() {
            $.ajax({
                    url:"D:/Python programs/django_projects/Noise_Measurement/noise_m/views.py/ajax_data/",
                    //success: updateValue(), for experimenting with a recursive call...
                });
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var v = setInterval(updateValue,2000);
        });
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
      <p>Hello there</p>
      <p>Present noise level : {{noise_level}} dB</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(I have mentioned rest of the code in my previously asked question. I have read some of the answers on the platform but I'm not getting much results.)

**Update**

Sorry I made a mistake. I made slight changes in the code and posted output without that only. Now I have made the exact changes as in the previous part. But output is not sorted out yet. (Thanks to comment by CumminUp07)

[image]

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: oh yes! I got some error. Actually I kept method call in index() of views.py, so reading was still visible. Now I deleted that method, so some error came. That I am going to mention in updated question.

Comment: ok done. Answer will be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** Own answer on own question **

Oh sorry, actually it was a misunderstanding of the syntax from my side.

I was first supposed to create method in views.py, which will send the reading from the module taking it. Then for that method, I had to assign an url using path(), in a fashion like:

```
path('read', views.data_update1, name='readings'),
```

Then the ajax request was supposed to be made to **read** link:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "read",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(r) { ... }
  });
```

Then this method is conveniently called using setInterval method.

But finally at the line, the `{{ }}` didn't help, so the div where the value was to be displayed was assigned an id, whose value was updated on each call of the method.